# Applied armature doesn't "stick" to mesh while not applied does and I think I need to apply

Tags: animation, armature, unity, nla-editor, actions

According to a tutorial that shows how to export my NLA to Unity I need to apply all modifiers first. Though, I noticed that if I apply my armature to the mesh then the mesh stops following the armature. I also have a mask modifier on the mesh that maybe makes some fuss. But it doesn't seem to matter if I apply both modifiers in any other order. The mesh still does not follow the armature. I've appended the blend file in comments if someone could take a look.

[image: How I want it to look when applying armature]

[image: How it actually looks when applying armature]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5873" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5873/)

Comment: Please use a specific title descriptive of your issue, and avoid writing extraneous text like "please help" and "questions"

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply the armature modifier.